# Can I neatly skip all or part of a mySQL script (esp that contains creation of stored procedures)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mySQL script, that I have to execute, but for a bunch of useless reasons (and more importantly boring), I might want it to skip most of that script.

Let's say before each part of the script I want to check `select okToRun from options` returns true before running the script.

So my script looks something like this

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure1$$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1()
  BEGIN
  IF (select okToRun from options) THEN 
  ... -- do some stuff
  END IF;
END$$

CALL procedure1()$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure2$$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure2()
  BEGIN
  IF (select okToRun from options) THEN 
  ... -- do some other stuff
  END IF;
END$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure3$$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure3()
  BEGIN
  IF (select okToRun from options) THEN 
  ... -- do even more stuff!
  END IF;
END$$

CALL procedure2()$$
CALL procedure3()$$
```

I hate repeated code, so how can I put the check right at the start of the script, rather than having to keep repeating myself?

I thought I'd be clever and wrap the whole thing in one stored procedure and do my if statement there... but you can't really create a stored procedure within another. And I need to keep the other stuff within their own stored procedures.

I also realise it'd be better to do the check before executing the script at all, but, well, I can't ;)

If the answer simply is that I can't do this, fair enough. But I want to be sure before repeating code like a big fat heathen.

Comment: I think you mean to have your `IF` surrounding the drop/recreate block no? Not embedded inside the create. Ah nvm I kept reading.

Comment: You tag your question `mysql` but then you link to an article on Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Which of these database products are you actually using?

Comment: my bad @Bill Karwin, I'd scanned the article and posted this in a rush. I thought it was referring to preparing and executing statements like you mention below. Have removed link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL client script syntax does not support conditionals or loops or other programming logic.

The best idea I could come up with is to use prepared statements, but unfortunately `CREATE PROCEDURE` is not supported in this manner.

```
SET @do_create := true;
SET @create_proc1 := IF(@do_create, 'CREATE PROCEDURE ...', 'DO 1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @create_proc1
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR 1295 (HY000): This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet
```

The list of commands supported in this way is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

In MySQL 5.7, they introduced a new client shell called [mysqlsh](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell.html) that is supposed to support a more featureful scripting environment, allowing you to write Python code and so on. I haven't tried this tool yet.

But you could do the same thing by writing your own script in Python or any other language you want. Then you can code the conditional logic to create procedures or whatever. That's your best bet.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Karwin, happy to accept there's no way, given you've come up with the only thing that would work (using prepared statements) and it's unsupported.

Incidentally it did dawn on me, I could at the very least just wrap the calls to the stored procedures within a separate stored procedure, and then use a single if block in that... but that doesn't help skip the other statements in the script (outside of stored procedures).

As you say, scripting is probably the way forward.